# datatables.net custom filter for more than one column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want a filtering in my datatable MS-crm-like (contains, does not contain, begins with, greater than....) for every column.

I've tried it the way as it was explained in this example: 
http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

the problem is that this filter only works for current column (for one column), so if I filter for column A and afterwards I want to filter for column B too, the filter of column A is obsolate.

Everytime I call `oTable.draw()` it will be refiltered for the current column.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is for older version of jQuery DataTables. See [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) for the current version.

Treat `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` (or `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search`) as array of functions. Reset the array first, add as many functions as you need and then call [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) API method.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Handle click on "Search" button
$('#btn-search').on('click', function(){
   // Reset custom search
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search = [];

   // Add search criteria for column 1 
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function( settings, data, dataIndex ){
         // ... skipped ...

         return (success) ? true : false;
      }
   );

   // Add search criteria for column 2
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function( settings, data, dataIndex ){
         // ... skipped ...

         return (success) ? true : false;
      }
   );

   // Perform the search
   table.draw();
});
```